# Bootstrap 3 submodals?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen that a working twitter bootstrap sub modal plugin works for older versions of bootstrap but it's not been updated to v3 by the author it seems.

I did change the markup to align with v3 but it seems like the CSS/JS needs some extra 'hacking'. Has anyone found a workaround this or some other plugin that allows this feature that they could share? much appreciated

github https://github.com/jakiestfu/Bootstrap-SubModal

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chou_one/eS7us/3/

```
<!-- Sub-Modal -->
<div id="mySubModal" class="modal sub-modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="center">Are you sure you want to close your account?<br />You won't be able to undo this.</p>
        <hr />
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>             
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="submodal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="submodal">Close Account</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't nest the html structures of your modal and submodal it seems you don't need any additional code. Example: http://bootply.com/85842

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>
</div>
</div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mysubModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>






        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

 <div class="modal fade" id="mysubModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: wow this sorts out my problem. i was nesting it inside the parent modal all the while and it was breaking it! Thanks @Bass

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author. Bootstrap Submodal is now for 3.x versions of bootstrap only. Hope you have enjoyed using it, sorry this is a late response!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to control the 'z-index' for modal and 'modal-open' class for body.

NOTICE: don't add the submodal html code inside of the modal.

```js
$ ->
  $('.modal').on 'show.bs.modal', ->
    $('.modal.in').css('zIndex', 0)

  $('.modal').on 'hidden.bs.modal', ->
    $('.modal.in').css('zIndex', '')
    setTimeout (->
      if $('.modal.in').length
        // it seems it will remove the modal-open after 'hidden.bs.modal', so add a setTimeout
        $('body').addClass('modal-open')
    ), 500
```